# Need help in figuring out why my 3d model is not being rendered in the browser

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to three.js and 3D model rendering and have been playing around with this sample code that i found on the internet. My aim here is to be able to render my 3D model using the chrome browser.

The default code is :

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );

    camera.position.z = 5;

    var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    animate();
```

When i go to my browser and type in http://localhost:8080/ i get a cube rotating

Now i try modifying the code to

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 200;

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
    controls.enableZoom = true;

     var keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 100%, 75%)'), 1.0);
     keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);

    var fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(240, 100%, 75%)'), 0.75);
    fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);

     var backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
     backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();

     scene.add(keyLight);
     scene.add(fillLight);
     scene.add(backLight);

     var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
     mtlLoader.setTexturePath('/examples/3d-obj-loader/assets/');
     mtlLoader.setPath('/examples/3d-obj-loader/assets/');
     mtlLoader.load('r2-d2.mtl', function (materials) {

     materials.preload();

      var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
      objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
      objLoader.setPath('/examples/3d-obj-loader/assets/');
      objLoader.load('r2-d2.obj', function (object) {

      scene.add(object);
      object.position.y -= 60;

      });

     });

    var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();
```

This should give me an image of r2-d2 model being rendered but i see a blank screen

I would really appreciate help in understanding what i am missing.

Comment: You need to confirm there's no errors in your JavaScript console first.

Comment: Your loader paths are probably wrong.

Comment: If no JS errors, you can try :
1) Try to load your model on any online tool (for example, https://threejs.org/editor/ ) to see if it's loading; Does it appear ? Is it black ? Is the model too big, too small ?
2) Check the material (it should be MeshStandardMaterial), when the model is load by console.log the scene.children, is it the expected material ?

Comment: Thank you for your help ! There were issues in the model i was using . Changed the model and this fixed the issue